# Stop automatic application execution on graphical login

Tags: process, startup, manjaro, autostart

I use Manjaro 20, and have changed the display manager from LightDM to SDDM, out of that and installing normal applications, I haven't changed anything on the system.

For some reason xfce4-terminal runs at login, just a normal terminal, however looking on the graphical interface *configurations -> session and startup* doesn't seem like I put the terminal to start in there.

I checked on several posts and tried many thing like checking systemd, `/etc/init.d`, cron, and checked  the "Autostarting" page from [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autostarting) checked the `.config/autostart`, but the xfce4-terminal doesn't seem to be listed on any of them. Honestly this is not a big ideal, I can just kill the process, but I would like to know how to solve it mostly to learn. Thanks in advance.

[image: ja]